# Error returned ''No database selected"

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to return data from two tables. I am getting a No database selected error. I am only learning so go easy on me your common sense. I thought I had the database selected up top, am I missing something some where else or have i just made another mess!? The first 6 td's are from the first table (custrec), the rest from table (contidr)
Here's the code

```
<?php
//connect to database
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'name', 'pass', 'Org_db');

// check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Connect failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno(); exit();
    }

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `custrec` 
          FULL OUTER JOIN `contidr` ON contidr.cid = custrec.`cid` WHERE custrec.`cid` = `1`");
if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); //  error handling
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Get queries - multiple Customer and contact details</title>

</head>

<body>
    <table width="80%" border="1px">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Customer ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Customer type</th>
        <th scope="col">Number of Children</th>
        <th scope="col">Animal Preference</th>
        <th scope="col">Vet ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Individual Contact ID Number</th>
        <th scope="col">First Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Address L1</th>
        <th scope="col">Address L2</th>
        <th scope="col">Town/City</th>
        <th scope="col">State</th>
        <th scope="col">Postcode</th>
        <th scope="col">Email</th>
        <th scope="col">Postcode</th>
      </tr>
<?php

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
  <tr>
    <td><? echo $row["$cid"]; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row["$cust_type"]; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row["$no_chd"]; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row["$aPref"]; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row["$vetId"]; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row["$icin"]; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row["$id_type"]; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row["$first_name"]; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row["$last_name"]; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row["$add_li1"]; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row["$add_li2"]; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row["$town_city"]; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row["$state"]; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row["$postcode"]; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row["$email"]; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row["$ph_area_code"]; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row["$phone"]; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row["$mobile"]; ?></td>   
  </tr>
<?php } 

/* close connection */
 $mysqli->close();
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to select a db after connection. Use mysql_select_db("<dbname>"); before calling any queries.

Comment: @Akshay you need to learn mysqli

Comment: I put in $mysql_select_db("Org_db");before query and got Undefined variable: mysql_select_db and Function name must be a string in, so took of $ and got "no db selected". Did I do it wrong?

Comment: You are mixing MySQL and MySQLi functions here.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - I was pointing to the fact that db wasn't selected. Thanks for the correction. user2042111 - I've posted answer with the relevant link.

Comment: @CBroe it have to be answer, not comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was noted in comments, **you are mixing mysql and mysqli**. And this is your problem.

For mysqli you already selected database but later you are using mysql functions, which causes the error. You have to use only mysqli functions.